# enter visual mode by highlighting in insert mode - nvim

Tags: neovim

I have seen some nvim users automatically enter visual mode when they are selecting code in insert mode. Is this set in .config. If so, how?

Have looked up in nvim options documentation but can't find anything

Comment: you mean enter visual selection mode from insert mode? If yes, you can do this via insert mode mappings easily.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not too sure but i think that you need to put this in your vimrc

```
set mouse=a
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).